# Binding value changes only once

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following View structure and run into the problem of the button working the first time I click and disabling the button like it should, but once I clicked one button it does not work for the other buttons. The Item is always the right one, I checked that by printing it out.

My `ReelsView`:

```
struct ReelsView: View {
    @State var currentReel = ""
    @State var items: [Item] = [
        Item(chance: "1:1m", tradeIn: 2000, name: "Apple Watch", price: "$200", rarityType: "common", description: "The Apple Watch", reel: Reel(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apple-watch", ofType: "mp4") ?? "")), bid: false)),
        Item(chance: "1:20m", tradeIn: 27500, name: "Ibiza vacation", price: "$2750,00", rarityType: "superRare", description: "Such a wonderful place for a vacation", reel: Reel(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ibiza", ofType: "mp4") ?? "")), bid: false)),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentReel) {
            ForEach($items) { $reel in
                ReelsPlayer(reel: $reel.reel, currentReel: $currentReel, item: $reel)
                    .tag(reel.reel.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ReelsPlayer`:

```
struct ReelsPlayer: View {
    @Binding var reel: Reel
    @Binding var currentReel: String
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let player = reel.player {
                CustomVideoPlayer(player: player)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            BottomOverlay(item: $item)
                .allowsHitTesting(true)
        }
    }
}
```

My `BottomOverlay`:

```
struct BottomOverlay: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            item.reel.bid.toggle()
            print("item: ", item)
            print("item: ", $item)
        } label: {
            Text(item.reel.bid ? "Already Bid" : "Bid")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Reel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var player: AVPlayer
    var bid: Bool
}
```

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(chance)
            hasher.combine(name)
            hasher.combine(price)
            hasher.combine(tradeIn)
            hasher.combine(rarityType)
            hasher.combine(description)
        }
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var chance: String
    var tradeIn: Int
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var rarityType: String
    var description: String
    var reel: Reel
}
```

Comment: dude, once you have `Button(){...}.disabled(item.clicked)`, then it is disabled,
  it cannot work again, that is what disabled mean. You have to re-enable it somewhere else, not
 in the same Button because it is now disabled.

Comment: But the button changes since it is a new View I create in the ForEach loop in my MainView. I also tried deleting the `.disabled()` and tried changing the name. It also does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used in my test, to show that the two buttons acts separately. Click on one, and it print the item id and state. Click on the other, and same for that item. If you un-comment `.disabled(item.clicked)`, then it only works once, because the Button (for that item) is now disabled.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var clicked: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = [Item(name: "item1", clicked: false),Item(name: "item2", clicked: false)]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($items) { $item in
            ItemView(item: $item)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.green
        }.overlay {
            OverlayView(item: $item)
        }
    }
}

struct OverlayView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 33){
            Button() {
                item.clicked.toggle()
                print("--> item.id: \(item)  item.clicked: \(item.clicked)")
            } label: {
                Text(item.name)
            }//.disabled(item.clicked)
            //            Button() {
            //                item.clicked.toggle()
            //            } label: {
            //                Text("enable again")
            //            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: in view of your new code. Try this example code, works well for me

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ReelsView()
    }
}

struct ReelsView: View {
    @State var currentReel = ""
    @State var items: [Item] = [
        Item(chance: "1:1m", tradeIn: 2000, name: "Apple Watch", price: "$200", rarityType: "common", description: "The Apple Watch", reel: Reel(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apple-watch", ofType: "mp4") ?? "")), bid: false)),
        Item(chance: "1:20m", tradeIn: 27500, name: "Ibiza vacation", price: "$2750,00", rarityType: "superRare", description: "Such a wonderful place for a vacation", reel: Reel(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ibiza", ofType: "mp4") ?? "")), bid: false)),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentReel) {
            ForEach($items) { $item in
                ReelsPlayer(currentReel: $currentReel, item: $item) // <-- here
                    .tag(item.reel.id)
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(.page)  // <-- here
    }
}

struct ReelsPlayer: View {
    @Binding var currentReel: String
    @Binding var item: Item  // <-- here
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let player = item.reel.player {  // <-- here
                //  CustomVideoPlayer(player: player)
                // for testing
                VStack {
                    if item.name == "Apple Watch" { Color.yellow } else { Color.green }
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            BottomOverlay(item: $item)
                .allowsHitTesting(true)
        }
    }
}

struct BottomOverlay: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            item.reel.bid.toggle()
            print("----> BottomOverlay item.reel.bid: ", item.reel.bid)  // <-- here
        } label: {
            Text(item.reel.bid ? "Already Bid" : "Bid")
        }
    }
}

struct Reel: Identifiable, Hashable {  // <-- here
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var player: AVPlayer
    var bid: Bool
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {  // <-- here
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var chance: String
    var tradeIn: Int
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var rarityType: String
    var description: String
    var reel: Reel
}
```

Comment: Yes and that is what I am expecting. To have 2 different buttons that each hold the value of clicked for the item that is passed. But I want to be able to change the clicked variable to true and this is where the problem occurs. It changes the first time I press the button when I call `item.clicked.toggle()` but after that it always prints true although it should change again if the button is not disabled. Also the other button does not change the value of the item when you press the other button first.

Comment: use my code as it is, it will work. You are probably using some other code that you are not showing. Try just my code.

Comment: Hm okay you're right. So I guess the error is somewhere else in my code

Comment: Printing `item.clicked` returns true and printing `$item.clicked` returns false. So it seems like my binding does not work correctly, right? Is there a way to do something like this `$item.clicked.toggle()` instead of just `item.clicked.toggle()`? Also it prints this for the binding value: `(unknown context at $18ee7d3f0).ScopedLocation>`. The second time I print it prints both  false.

Comment: Show a minimal example code that reproduces your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Currently what you say does not make sense without the code you are using.

Comment: I updated the code and tried to include everything that could lead to the error

Comment: On which line do you get the error. I do not get any errors in my tests, all works well.

Comment: updated may answer (EDIT-1), in view of your new code.

Comment: I get it when I print out this ` print("item: ", $item)`

Comment: don't really understand what you mean, `print("item: ", item)` would work just as well. Does my code not work for you?

Comment: The code works fine now :) The button changes for every individual View! It is what I get as output for the print. I don't know whether this is an issue I should care about since your code works fine for me